# org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 13; Element type "parameters" must be declared

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here is the xml file and not sure what is missing here . Any suggestions here?

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestSuite" parallel="tests">
<test name="FireFox Test">
<parameters>
    <parameter name="platform" value="Windows" />
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
    <parameter name="version" value="62.0.3" />
    <parameter name="url" value="http://www.expedia.com" />
</parameters>
    <classes>
        <class name="testClasses.SeleniumGrid_ParallelTestFramework">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Chrome Test">
<parameters>
    <parameter name="platform" value="Windows" />
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="version" value="85.0.4183.121" />
    <parameter name="url" value="http://www.expedia.com" />
</parameters>
    <classes>
        <class name="testClasses.SeleniumGrid_ParallelTestFramework">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

The full exception details are here

```
org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 13; Element type "parameters" must be declared.
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:324)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:109)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 13; Element type "parameters" must be declared.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:170)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:304)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1):

TestNG *test* tag doesn't have a *parameters*.

Try just add many *parameter* entries.

```
<test name="FireFox Test">
    <parameter name="platform" value="Windows" />
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
    <parameter name="version" value="62.0.3" />
    <parameter name="url" value="http://www.expedia.com" />
    <classes>
        <class name="testClasses.SeleniumGrid_ParallelTestFramework">
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Tutorial [here](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/testng-example-to-create-testng-xml/).
[image]

Comment: Tried removing the <parameters> tag from testng.xml and the program is compiled successfully. Thank you for the response.

Comment: You are welcome. If you could mark the answer as Accepted, the community would appreciate.